# How to solve the sawtooth when plot?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot[(x^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 2)^3 == x^2*(y + 1)^3, {x, -3.2, 
  3.2}, {y, -3.2, 3.2}, ContourStyle -> {Black}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> False, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]
```

You will find output is not smooth as expect,even I output as EPS format.
How to solve this problem? Or other software suggestion.
Thanks!

Comment: try adding option `PlotPoints->50`

Comment: try `PlotPoints -> 150` and/or `MaxRecursion -> 5`?

Comment: Even I set PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 10 ,still can see a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) and select real solutions (in addition to increasing [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) with/without increasing [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)):

```
ans = y /. {ToRules[
    Reduce[(x^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 2)^3 == x^2*(y + 1)^3, {x, y}]]};
f[a_?NumericQ, n_] := ans[[n]] /. x -> a
Plot[{f[x, 1], f[x, 2]}, {x, -3, 3}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: You can find there's a break point

Comment: @kittygirl I take your point. I did not increase `PlotPoints` for this (as I suggested in my comment for ContourPlot). You may prefer to do that. Good luck. Merely wanted to illustrate other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `PlotPoints->50` in your plot definition. You can increase the number to more than 50 if you need higher smoothing..[image]

Comment: even I set Plotponts to 250, still has break point at H:722.86, W:408.17 px. At that point, the curve is not smooth.